# How to prove elements within sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Let $D=[3x^3+2: x \in \mathbb{Z}]$.

Prove that

1. $-1 \in D$
2. $5 \in D$
3. $0 \notin D$
4. $1/2 \notin D$

How do I go about proving something like this? Do I just need to show an example?

Comment: Yes and no.   $-1\in D$ iff $-1=3x^3+2$ has an integer solution for $x.$  And $0\not \in D$  iff  $0=3x^3+2$ has no integer solution $x.$  The usual notation for $D$ is $D=\{3x^3+2: x\in \mathbb Z\}$ which says literally that anything belongs to $D$ iff  it is equal to $3x^3+2$ for some integer $x.$

Answer (score 1):

To show that $y \in D$ you have to find an $x \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $y=3x^3 + 2$.

To show $y$ is not in $D$ you have to give an argument why the equation $y = 3x^3 + 2$ has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}$. 4. is easy: all members of $D$ are integers by their form. For $y=0$ note that $3x^3 = -2$ has no integer solution (just the one real, irrational one). For $-1$ and $5$ you have to find $x$, which is not too hard.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

You could actually prove by showing if a specific value satisfies the description of the set $D$ or not.

Could you continue now?

Comment: Is that all it takes.. so for example #1. Let $x =-1$, then $-1 \in D$?

Comment: yep, the set $D$ is defined as all integers that satisfies the description.

Comment: How would I show that 0 is not an element of D?

Comment: @Mitchell could you find an integer $x$ such that $3x^3 +2 =0$?

Comment: No, but how can I formally prove that?

Comment: @Mitchell you could just solve the equation - $x=-\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{3}}$ which is not an integer

Answer (score 0):

proving an element is in a set just requires an example, proving an element is not in a set requires a proof in this case the fact that $3x^3$ is never a fraction nor equal to 2 when x is an integer

for -1 in D we have $x=-1$ in z

for 5 in D we have $x=1$ in z

note we could also prove that the elements are not in the set by exaugstion with the mean value theorem that a solution for 0 or. requires x between -1 and 1 and we note $x=0$ gives 2 in D

Comment: How would you formally prove the last part?

Comment: we have a monotonically increasing function. f(a)<f(y)<f(c) then a<y<c